# How to define 'public' and 'private' interfaces to an object?

Tags: c#, interface

I have a database and a DAL class that manages object-to-data (and vice-versa) mapping, in a similar way to Entity Frameworks - but we can't use EF here yet, so the DAL is a quite simple home-grown library that exposes a few objects and allows actions to be performed on them. It works, and will do until we can go to a 'proper' EF solution.

The DAL offers a variety of objects to 'client' applications, with methods and properties defined to encapsulate the logic of each action and hide the internal state of those objects as well as the mechanics needed to persist them to the database. This works too.

However, there are some actions that are exposed by the DALs' object interfaces which should really be 'private' - they are used by a service application that runs elsewhere, doing various background stuff to the objects in the database. I do not really want the 'client' applications to be able to see these methods, but I *do* want the methods to be visible when the DAL is referenced by the service application.

Example of the current implementation:

> ```
> DAL Library
>   Object
>     Method LoadObject()
>     Method SaveObject()
>     Method AdjustInternalObjectProperty()
> ```

Thus, the client apps can see all three methods, though they should never use the third - that is a function that should only be visible to the service app (which should be able to see and use all three methods).

So the question is, what is the best approach to take which will preserve the intention of using interfaces to each object, but which will 'hide' parts of that interface and only make the hidden parts accessible to a suitably 'friendly' service app. Is there some access modifier technique that will let me make certain parts of the interface 'private', with a mechanism that the service app uses (but the client does not) to gain access to those private elements? Or is this a scenario where two different interfaces should exist, where the 'client' interface simply omits the 'internal' methods? Or something else?

I want to do this the 'right' way - I've searched SO and found a bunch of answered questions regarding multiple object interfaces, but none seem to quite hit the spot for my specific question. If there *is* an existing answer, by all means point me at it and close this question.

**EDIT (after reading answers and experimenting):**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Test")]

namespace Interface_Test
{
  public interface IStandard
  {
    void StandardMethod();
  }
  internal interface ISuper : IStandard
  {
    void SuperMethod();
  }

  public sealed class TestClass : ISuper
  {
    public void StandardMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The standard method");
    }
    void ISuper.SuperMethod()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The super method");
    }
  }
}
```

This does the job - the bulk of the object exposure is through the `IStandard` interface, which is a bog-standard public interface that any and all client assemblies can use. The 'restricted' stuff is only accessible through the alternate `ISuper` interface, which inherits all the core stuff from `IStandard` but adds the extra items that I only want a specific 'service client' to use. By adding the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute as suggested, this interface and its' methods/properties are completely invisible to all but the named assembly.

The downside is that there are two interfaces, but in the absence of a language facility such as allowing `'internal'` as a modifier on interface method definitions it's a reasonable way of ensuring client assemblies can't get to features the interface supports but which aren't for general use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is:

- Create an `internal` interface
- Implement it *explicitly* (to avoid requiring public methods)
- Use [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to give your "service application" access to the internal interface

You may be interested in [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/03/the-curious-case-of-the-publicity-seeking-interface-and-the-shy-abstract-class.aspx) which shows a few interesting options for other situations.

Comment: yes this will work but this looks like a .NET hack while I believe this needs to be *baked into the interfaces* as is **part of the design**.

Comment: @Aliostad: I'm not sure I'd call it a "hack" really... and it *is* baking it into the interfaces, having one internal API and one public one.

Comment: This plus the interface inheritance answer got me a solution - answer accepted. :)

Answer (score 3):

One common approach is to have 2 interfaces:

```
public interface IBar
{
   void DoSimpleStudd();
   int This {get;}

}

public interface ISuperBar : IBar
{
   void DoComplexStuff();
   int That {get; set;}

}

// at service layer
public class ServiceWidget
{
    public ISuperBar Bar {get; set;}
    ...
}

// other places
public class ServiceWidget
{
    public IBar Bar {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

So in the `service layer`, they will be using `ISuperBar` and in other parts of the application, they will use `IBar`.

### UPDATE

Yes, interfaces are meant to be public.

Comment: Are these meant to be public interfaces? If so, how would the ISuperBar be hidden from the client applications? Either the class implements it or it doesn't.

Comment: @Jon Yes, they are public - I just omitted that as I was making a point. It would not be hidden. IoC will be configured to return the same implementation but at UI, dependency will have be as `IBar` while service objects will have a reference to `ISuperBar`

Comment: @Aliostad: Without even mentioning IoC, that was somewhat unclear :) I still don't think this meets the stated goal of "only make the hidden parts accessible to a suitably 'friendly' service app". It looks to me like *any* app could just request the more powerful interface.

Comment: @Job Thanks Jon, I appreciate your input. I see visibility as a concept in object interaction design - and language neutral - hence would stick to basic OO principles rather than using language features to fix it. But as I said your approach is completely valid and solves the problem.

Comment: +1 because this, combined with the accepted answer, got me a solution. :)